# Example of symbol of generalized Toeplitz operators

Tags: analysis

I am looking for the example to the sybol of generalized Toeplitz operators.
For example if Toeplitz operator is matrix (S*  O // 0  S) we have the symbol is matrix Y= (M_{\pH}   0 // 0   0). I do not know how we know that this Y is symbole for T?
What is when we take T as matrix (S*  0 // 0  S*)  or T as matrix (I   0// 0   S*) .
 **How look symbol for this T.** And what I sholud do to obtain this symbol
Where S i shift, an I is identity